# Recorrer una lista con angularjs

Tags: angularjs

tengo un error al guardar una lista en angularjs

al revisar con está enviando los datos al guardar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        $scope.agregarTecnologiaSeleccionado = function (tecnologia) {

        $scope.solicitud.IdSolicitudTecnologia = tecnologia.Id;

        $scope.listaTecnologiaSeleccionada.push(tecnologia);

        $scope.solicitud.Tecnologia = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listaTecnologiaSeleccionada.length; i++) {

            var tecnologia = [
                {
                      Id: $scope.listaTecnologiaSeleccionada[i].Id
                    , Nombre: $scope.listaTecnologiaSeleccionada[i].Nombre
                }
            ];

            $scope.solicitud.Tecnologia.push(tecnologia);
        }

        console.log($scope.solicitud.Tecnologia);
    }
```

No me guardar ya que veo que envia un arreglo dentro de otro.
Como hago para solucionarlo?

muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto, es mas facil

```
angular.forEach($scope.listaTecnologiaSeleccionada, function(value, key){
     var tecnologia = {
         Id : key,
         Nombre : value
     }
     $scope.solicitud.Tecnologia.push(tecnologia);
   });
```

sin embargo, el detalle en tu codigo es aqui:

```
var tecnologia = [
                {
               Id: $scope.listaTecnologiaSeleccionada[i].Id
                        , Nombre: $scope.listaTecnologiaSeleccionada[i].Nombre
                }
];
```

ya que estas agregando primero en un Array, y aedntro de ese array estas creando un Object, es decir Array = [] y Object = {}

Ojala te funcione

Comment: Esa era la respuesta, muchas gracias